# When created only for assigning to a delegate, is it optimal to employ methods or readonly delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, readonly

readonlyAction and Method must both be defined once, but assume I will assign to variableAction many times:

```
Action variableAction;
readonly Action readonlyAction;
void Method() {}
```

Which is better suited to the task, the readonly delegate, or the method?  I'm thinking that there may be some optimizations happening in one case or the other, but maybe there are semantic issues to consider as well?

```
variableAction = readonlyAction;
variableAction = Method;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one setting up either the method or the action (pre-compilation) (which you probably would not be asking this if you werent), then I would assume that there is not a whole lot of difference performance-wise. But, you should take a look at the IL if you want the exact answer. The compiler might just create a method or inline for a static action anyway. That being said, I would focus on readability more than anything else at that point. Try to imagine a new dev trying to read the code, and if one way makes it harder to read, then use the other way....I would probably lean towards a method personally. Actions should probably be left for the scenario below:

Otherwise, the `Action` could be something that is passed in on construction, so you would HAVE to use the `Action` since you would not know the implementation until runtime anyway. But, I doubt that is why you are asking, as using the `Method` would be impossible in this scenario, anyway.